# Mounting a gimbal BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-motor

I'm trying to build my own motorised camera gimbal using a BLDC like [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2pcs-Ipower-brushless-motor-2804-100T-hollow-shaft-free-shipping/1755685_32355221325.html), where the shaft is hollow. Does anyone know how the camera platform should be mounted? Should a shaft be somehow pressed into the hole?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: That particular motor is open-loop (no feedback). How would you control it?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* John Munroe, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions that ask for a **list of approaches** or a **subjective recommendation on a method** (for *how to build something*, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On gimbal motors, the two sides of the motor casing are the mounting points. The hollow shaft allows you to feed wiring through the motor.

If you look at the motor you have linked more carefully the two sides are split and have bolt holes on them. So you just mount the motor with those.